# update in nested sql with count match

Tags: sql

The following SELECT Query works fine:

```
select
    StringField_1
    , StringField_2
    , StringField_3
    , COUNT(*)
from my.table
where StringField_1 in (
    select StringField_1
    from my.table
)
group by
    StringField_1
    , StringField_2
    , StringField_3
having
    COUNT(*) > 10
    and StringField_3 like '.*some_string_here.*'
;
```

The Results:

```
|StringField_1  | StringField_2 | StringField_3 |
|-------------- | ------------- | ------------- |
```

(0 rows affected)

But the UPDATE with the above output fails:

```
update my.table
set
    StringField_1 = 'CLEAR'
    , numField_1 = 0
where StringField_1 in (
    select
        StringField_1
        , StringField_2
        , StringField_3
        , COUNT(*)
    from my.table
    where StringField_1 in (
        select StringField_1
        from my.table
    )
    group by
        StringField_1
        , StringField_2
        , StringField_3
    having COUNT(*) > 10 and StringField_3 like '.*some_string_here.*'
);
```

With the following error:

> ERROR=Illegal the selection list must not contain both aggregate and column expressions on line 3 of statement 'update my.table set StringField_1 = 'CLEAR', numField= 0 where
>   StringField_1  in (select StringField_1 , StringField_12, StringField_13, COUNT(*)  from my.table where StringField_1  in (select StringField_1  from my.table) group b...', at or near 'group'

Any clues?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The `IN` clause must only return one column:

```
where StringField_1 in (select StringField_1 
                        from my.table 
                        group by StringField_1, StringField_2, StringField_3 
                        having COUNT(*) > 10 
                            and StringField_3 LIKE '.*some_string_here.*');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't return multiple columns in a subquery like that.  Also, no need to use the following:

```
where StringField_1 in (select StringField_1 from my.table)
```

Try something like this instead:

```
update my.table
set StringField_1 = 'CLEAR', 
    numField_1 = 0
where StringField_1 in (
    select StringField_1
    from my.table 
    group by StringField_1, StringField_2, StringField_3 
    having count(*) > 10 
        and StringField_3 like '.*some_string_here.*'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery should only return a single column (StringField_1)

Also, `where StringField_1 in (select StringField_1 from my.table)` is redundant, you don't need it.

I also moved the `where StringField_3 like '.*some_string_here.*'` up into the where clause as it will mean there are fewer rows to aggregate, but the result should be the same..

```
update my.table 
set StringField_1 = 'CLEAR', numField_1 = 0 
where StringField_1 in 
(
 select distinct StringField_1
 from my.table 
 where StringField_3 like '.*some_string_here.*'
 group by StringField_1, StringField_2, StringField_3 
 having COUNT(*) > 10 
);
```